# PHP PDO long sql statement no response

Tags: php, sql, pdo, limit

We use PHP 5.3.2, Ubuntu, MySQL 5.1.41, CodeIgniter 2.0.0 with simple PDO driver.

Problem is if we send a long string (about 11, 12 kbytes in size) in a query, neither PHP, neither the MySQL returns any errors or responses.
No syntax errors, no warnings, no HTTP errors, no nothing. The PHP just keeps "pending".

If the data string is shorter by a few kbytes, the query runs and the data is inserted to the database correctly.

We believe that the MySQL doesn't even get the query that we sent if it's larger than ~11kbytes.

Either `PDO::prepare` or `PDOStatement::execute` fails.

The query:

```
select simpleupdatestoredprocedure(15, 'loooong string');
```

Function called:

```
function _execute($sql)
{
    $q = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();

    return $q; 
}
```

Where `$this->conn` is the main PDO object and `$q` is a `PDOStatement` object. (We do not use any CodeIgniter specific stuff in this part of code.)

Is there some hidden setting that limits the length of data or query that can be passed?
If necessary, we'll find the exact number of bytes when this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried trapping any exceptions? I had the same trouble with an Oracle PDO driver and it was exceeding some buffer somewhere. The Oracle one though is experimental so it's probably expected with that. Have you checked your PHP error log?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) needs to be big enough to contain the entire query.